# Quickblox frequent crash in Android

Tags: android, chat, quickblox, quickblox-android

I have been working with Quickblox SDK for past few weeks and have developed applications with features of one-to-one, group chat as well as WebRTC too. 
I am using **3.0** version of the SDK due to some of my requirements and I will not be able to change it.

There is one crash which I am frequently facing in my app in no specific screen. I have reported this to Quickblox as well but did not help much.

The crash log is as below :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
at com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatDialog.initChat (Unknown Source)
at com.quickblox.chat.model.QBChatDialog.initChatFromRest (Unknown Source)
at com.quickblox.chat.model.QBDialogDeserializer.deserialize (Unknown Source)
at com.quickblox.chat.model.QBDialogDeserializer.deserialize (Unknown Source)
at com.google.a.v.b (Unknown Source)
at com.google.a.b.a.l.b (Unknown Source)
at com.google.a.b.a.b$a.a (Unknown Source)
at com.google.a.b.a.b$a.b (Unknown Source)
at com.google.a.b.a.i$1.a (Unknown Source)
at com.google.a.b.a.i$a.b (Unknown Source)
at com.google.a.f.a (Unknown Source)
at com.google.a.f.a (Unknown Source)
at com.google.a.f.a (Unknown Source)
at com.quickblox.core.parser.QBJsonParser.parseJsonResponse (Unknown Source)
at com.quickblox.core.parser.QBLimitedJsonParser.parseJsonResponse (Unknown Source)
at com.quickblox.core.parser.QBJsonParser.parse (Unknown Source)
at com.quickblox.core.Query$a.completedWithResponse (Unknown Source)
at com.quickblox.core.Query.completedWithResponse (Unknown Source)
at com.quickblox.core.server.HttpRequestRunnable$1.handleMessage (Unknown Source)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:111)
at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:238)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6006)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:937)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:798)
```

Just to be noted, I could not find any file with method using any of mentioned in crash log like **initChat()** or anything else and crash can come to any of the screen in app. So not sure which code I should share here.
I would be thankful for any suggetions.

Comment: please answer me, did you test my recommendation below, what is result?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you load dialogs and not logged in to the chat in this moment. Use latest version of QuickBlox Android SDK with fix this issue.